# Is the product of two Jacobian matrices equal to the locally linear approximation of the original functions?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, function-and-relation-composition, jacobian, linear-approximation

For two $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions $\vec g: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\vec f: \mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}^k$ does the equality hold

$$\mathbf{J}_{\vec f} \mathbf{J}_{\vec g} \approx \vec f \circ \vec g$$

where $\approx$ denotes locally linear approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\textbf{J}_f$ is evaluated at $g(x)$, then yes. Letting $\textbf{J}_f(x)$ denote the Jacobian evaluated at $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, the correct approximation is $(f\circ g)(x)\approx \textbf{J}_f(g(x))\cdot\textbf{J}_g(x)$.

For a differentiable function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the *best linear approximation of $h$* at a point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined rigorously with the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map), which is a linear map $(Dh)(a):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ that best resembles the behavior of $h$ near $a$. If all the first-order partial derivatives of $h$ are continuous at $a$, the map $(Dh)(a)$ is just the Jacobian at $a$: $(Dh)(a)=\textbf{J}_h(a)$.

The total derivative has a chain rule; assuming any necessary domain and codomain restrictions, we have $D(f\circ g)(x)=(Df)(g(x))\circ(Dg)(x)$. When the linear maps are given by matrices, the composition becomes matrix multiplication, explaining where the approximation $(f\circ g)(x)\approx \textbf{J}_f(g(x))\cdot\textbf{J}_g(x)$ comes from.